# Why does SQLAlchemy boolean column fail with "TypeError: an integer is required, found str"

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Here's an answer your own question to help other out who may also hit this error.

I'm using SQLite3 from Python and using SQLAlchemy to load my objects via the ORM. I have a column specified as:

```
the_column = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
```

I have manually added a **boolean** column to my table via:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD the_column INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL;
```

Yet when I run the app I get the error:

**TypeError: an integer is required, found str**. Or something like this.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the default value. Booleans in SQLAlchemy map to integers in the DB (I did create the right type of column) but the default value of FALSE wasn't translated via the DDL command to an integer value of 0.

The fix is to create the column as so:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD the_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```