# SQLAlchemy giving TypeError reading strings from SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, typeerror, fetchall

Here is code to read the data out of the tables in a SQLite database:

```
db_path = 'test.db'

import sqlalchemy as db
engine = db.create_engine('sqlite:///'+db_path)
inspector = db.inspect(engine)
table_names = inspector.get_table_names()
conn = engine.connect()
md = db.MetaData()

for tname in table_names:
    table = db.Table(tname, md, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    print('Table ' + tname + ' columns: ' + str(table.columns.keys()))
    query = db.select([table])
    table_data = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
    for tdata in table_data:
        print('Data row: ' + str(tdata))
```

Here's the output from the working version:

```
Table address columns: ['id', 'email_address', 'user_id']
Table user_account columns: ['id', 'name', 'fullname']
Data row: (1, 'sandy', 'Sandy Cheeksworth')
Data row: (2, 'johnny boy', 'John Snow')
Data row: (3, 'fred', 'Fred Flintstone')
Data row: (4, 'barney', 'Barney Rubble')
Data row: (5, 'squidward', 'Squidward Tentacles')
Data row: (6, 'ehkrabs', 'Eugene H. Krabs')
Data row: (7, 'snoop', 'Calvin Cordozar Broadus Jr.')
Data row: (8, 'jay-z', 'Shawn Corey Carter')
>>>
```

If I use SQLiteStudio to change the 2nd field from type varchar to type string, things get ugly. Here's the "pre-debugged" output:

```
Table address columns: ['id', 'email_address', 'user_id']
Table user_account columns: ['id', 'name', 'fullname']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 992, in fetchall
    return self._allrows()
  File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 402, in _allrows
    made_rows = [make_row(row) for row in rows]
  File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 402, in <listcomp>
    made_rows = [make_row(row) for row in rows]
TypeError: must be real number, not str
>>>
```

I've only been learning SQLAlchemy for a couple days and I'm really new to database stuff as well... so I assume I'm doing *something* wrong... or does SQLAlchemy just not work well with string data in SQLite?  Why does it want a "real number" where column specifies a string, but it's fine with a varchar?  This is a small demo database, but I have a large database... should I change all the string fields to varchar?  TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it as `TEXT`. If you declare it as `STRING`, it has affinity of `NUMERIC`, not `TEXT`

Have a look at [Datatypes In SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), especially [the last sentence in the examples](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples).

> And the declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not
> TEXT.

This will cause SQLAlchemy to fail. Have a look also at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48462859/4046632)